# Last column does not appear on screen in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

1. I create a JTable at runtime. The number of columns will vary from a few to hundreds.
2. I have a database routine which populates a vector of vectors.
3. The topmost row is used as the header.
4. The data in the columns vary in size, and the column sizes are computed and set to the maximum width for that column. That is to say, each column will vary in size.
5. The table header in the table and the scroll pane are hidden via:

   ```
   Common.myTBL.setTableHeader(null);
   Common.myScrollPanel.setColumnHeaderView(null);
   Common.myScrollPanel.setViewportView(Common.myTBL);
   pack();
   ```
6. When the number of columns in the table is small -  say 5 or 6 - I don't have any problems.
7. `Common.myTBL.setAutoResizeMode(javax.swing.JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);`

But there is a particular case where the number of columns is 174 (0 to 173). The last column does not appear on the screen. I tried adding an extra dummy column (175th) and *part* of column 174 appeared.

8. This is the code that creates the Table Model and Table Object
   public void createTableModel() {
       int noOfColumns = 0;
       int noOfRows = 0;
       noOfRows = Common.tableData.size();
       noOfColumns = Common.tableData.get(0).size();
       System.out.println("\nNumber of Rows in the VECTOR = "+noOfRows);
       System.out.println("\nNumber of columns in the VECTOR = "+noOfColumns);
       Common.myTableModel = new AttributiveCellTableModel(noOfRows, noOfColumns);
       System.out.println("\nNumber of Rows in the MODEL= "+Common.myTableModel.getRowCount());
       System.out.println("\nNumber of columns in the MODEL = "+Common.myTableModel.getColumnCount());
       Common.theRoots = Common.tableData.get(0);
       Common.myTableModel.setDataVector(Common.tableData, Common.theRoots);
       Common.cellAtt = (CellSpan)Common.myTableModel.getCellAttribute();

   }

   public void createTableObject() {

   ```
   Common.myTBL = new MultiSpanCellTable(Common.myTableModel) {
       public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int Index_row, int Index_col) {
           Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, Index_row, Index_col);
           JComponent jcomp = (JComponent) comp;
           Common.originalBorder = jcomp.getBorder();

           comp.setBackground(setRowColor(Index_row));

           jcomp.setToolTipText(getToolTip(Index_row, Index_col));
           comp.setFont(Common.defaultFont14);
           comp.setForeground(setGenderColor(Index_row, Index_col));
           jcomp.setBorder(setBorderType(Index_row, Index_col));

           return comp;
       }

   };

   Common.myTBL.setRowHeight(25);
   Common.myTBL.setBorder(null);
   Common.myTBL.setAutoResizeMode(javax.swing.JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
   Common.myTBL.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
   Common.myTBL.setGridColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 51, 255));
   Common.myTBL.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
   Common.myTBL.revalidate();
   ```

   }

Comment: `JTable` has it's own header capabaility, it sounds like you've not added the table to a `JScrollPane`, but without a runnable example which demonstrates your issue, that's just guess work. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Can you show the minimal code required to reproduce?

Comment: If you use Java 8, why don't you use JavaFX instead? Or is that a legacy app?

Comment: The data is sitting in MySQL database? I am learning JAVA and tried creating my Genealogy. I have taken care of the Scroll Pane. Common.myScrollPanel.setColumnHeaderView(null);

Comment: I tried adding the screen shot but the system would not allow, saying I am new in here.

Comment: Creating the Table model and Table object are here.